# String with \n\n not creating <br>'s

Tags: javascript

My div of "description" class pulls in the following from an array:

```
[{ "id": "1", "text": "There are two.\n\nThe first one is..."}]
```

How can I ensure instead of it just creating the space it replaces the `\n\n` with a `<br /><br />`?

I've tried

```
document.getElementById(".description").innerHTML = myObj.text.replace(/\n/g,"<br /><br />");
```

but no luck.

Comment: Whoops! Correct, will fix that now, thanks!

Comment: updated :) thanks still no go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost looks like you may be trying to use a selector:

```
document.getElementById(".description").innerHTML = ...;
// TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

But, [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) expects just `id="..."` values. So, it'll be trying to find:

```
<div id=".description"></div>
```

If `description` is a `class` name:

```
<div class="description"></div>
```

You could try [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) instead (IE8+).

```
document.querySelector('.description').innerHTML = myObj.text.replace(/\n/g,"<br /><br />");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4xUwn/